# File write not working in PHP extension c/c++ (linux)

Tags: php, c++, file-io, centos7, php-internals

I have created my own PHP extension in c++ (linux).
when zend engine compiles the PHP code am getting the active user functions and internal functions name.

To debug this php extension am using **zend_printf** to print the values.

Instead of zend_printf wants to **write in log file**. 
I checked with FILE I/O, fstream not working here.

How to create the log file in php extension using c/c++?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my log file location. In my php extension had c++ code to open the file as follows,

fpo = fopen("/tmp/ResultRequest.txt", "a+");

But it created inside the location "**/tmp/systemd-private-*************-httpd.service-pRXgTf/tmp/ResultRequest.txt**"

This location will be deleted when you restart the apache server.